# keras/tensorflow model: gradient w.r.t. input return the same (wrong?) value for all input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, gradient

Given a trained `keras` model I am trying to compute the gradient of the output with respect to the input.

This example tries to fit the function `y=x^2` with a keras model composed by 4 layers of relu activations, and compute the gradient of the model output with respect to the input.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import backend as k
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# random data
x = np.random.random((1000, 1))
y = x**2

# split train/val
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.15)

# model
model = Sequential()
# 1d input
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(1, ), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
# 1d output
model.add(Dense(1))

## compile and fit
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=100, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), shuffle=True)

## compute derivative (gradient)
session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
y_val_d_evaluated = session.run(tf.gradients(model.output, model.input), feed_dict={model.input: x_val})

print(y_val_d_evaluated)
```

`x_val` is a vector of 150 random number between `0` and `1`.

My expectations is that `y_val_d_evaluated` (the gradient) should be:

A. an `array` of 150 different numbers (because `x_val` contains 150 different numbers);

B. the values should be near to `2*x_val` (the derivative of `x^2`).

Instead, every time I run this example, `y_val_d_evaluated` contains 150 equal values (e.g. `[0.0150494]`, `[-0.0150494]`, `[0.0150494]`, `[-0.0150494]`, ...), moreover the value is very different from `2x`, and the value change every time I run the example.

Anyone has some suggestions to help me to understand why this code does not give the expected gradient results?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found the problem, the following lines:

```
session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

create a new tf session that overwrites the model parameters, so after these instructions the model was a model with the random initial paramters. This explains why every run the value was different.

The solution to get the tensorflow session from a keras environment is to use:

```
session = k.get_session()
```

whith this simple change the results go as I expected.